# Why does a 12 V, 0.5 A fan work in a PSU but a 12 V, 0.125 A one does not? (Both are three wire fans)

Tags: voltage, current, ohms-law, fan

Completely new to electronics and I'm learning by trying to replace a bad PSU fan (bad bearing but no power problems to the fan). The original fan was 12 V, 0.5 A. I bought a rinky dink fan that was too small from Microcenter that was also 12 V and the amperage is not marked. I put it in there and this one worked but sounded like it was going a million miles an hour so I opted to buy some nice fans off of Amazon.

The new, nice fans run at 12 V, 0.12 A, however, no matter what combination I try (I tried all six) the new fans will not turn on. I retested with the crappy Microcenter fan and it still worked fine.

If I understand it correctly, the amperage being lower than the original means that the fan would have to provide more resistance if it's a 0.12A fan. Is it possible that the fan has some circuitry in place which prevents it from running because the amperage is too high? (V=IR?)

### Original Fan

[image]

### New Fan

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B009NQMESS/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009NQMESS)

### PSU Three Wire Plug

[image]

### Testing the Fan (Update 1)

I talked to a buddy who was an avionics technician - he pointed out the obvious. You can test the fan with a 9 V battery - shown below, it works. I have already tested the connections many, many, times so I'm confident it's connected. He pointed out that in the case of things like iDRAC (out of band management for servers for those unfamiliar) it modulates the voltage dependent on the load. It is possible this fan has an operating range of say, 6-12 V whereas on boot, the computer may modulate the voltage down below some lower bound in which case the fan won't turn on. Next experiment: Use a 1.5 V battery.

[image]

### Update 2

I believe my friend's point has been proven - 1.5 V and the fan does nothing.

[image]

### Update 3

I've spent all night on this mostly out of curiosity trying pretty much every combination under the sun. I used a multimeter to check the connection and confirmed that only with positive to pin #2 and negative to pin #3 is there any registration so I can quite confidently say connection isn't the problem. What's absolutely odd is that even when off there is a constant voltage of ~0.4 V. When you turn it on it fluctuates and stabilizes at 0.2 V.

If you fire it up with the ohm meter you can watch it do some sort of probe at the beginning before stabilizing at around 6 ohms (even though the fan isn't working).

For whatever reason though, even though the circuit is complete, the board never provides more voltage. I confirmed this wasn't due to some passive power saving by turning on a very graphic intensive game that always has this thing screaming. It's obvious something is wrong because the CPU has downclocked. I noticed this behavior previously when testing several days ago - if either fan isn't spinning the CPU gets downclocked regardless of PSU temperature. Everything will start and run, but it will absolutely crawl. The test is easy to reproduce (if crude) stick a screwdriver in there to stop the fan from moving and watch how slow the computer goes. Then shutdown, let it spin freely, and it runs just fine.

### Update 4

Ladies and gents if nothing else we're learning. I know that both the fan from Amazon and from Microcenter both will turn on with a voltage between 3 - 4.5 V. 1 and 2 AA batteries in series did not work but three does so it's somewhere in between those values.

[image]

### Update 5

Ok, so what I did was take two Molex connectors from another computer, checked the voltage to make sure it was an even 12 V, then plugged those into the two PSU fans of the computer under test. Then I plugged the tach from those two PSU fans into the PSU of the computer under test. I have established that if the tach is registering, the computer under test runs like a champ. As soon as you remove the tach signal from either fan - the CPU downclocks.

[image]

Comment: Are you connecting these in series or parallel (correct)?

Comment: It's the slot on a computer PSU that says FAN1 and FAN2. I'm not really sure how the circuitry works.

Comment: Make and model number?

Comment: @Passerby Added pictures and info to OP!

Comment: If you connect it to a HD power connector using the adapter that comes with it, does it turn on?

Comment: If your fan works on a separated system and your power supply works with other fans the first thing that comes to mind is that the cable is not connected properly. This can be bad electric connected, solder failures etc. Or the pins does not match in the cable connection. Check continuity and if the vcc is connected to vcc, gnd to gnd and so on.
As you fan is rated below your original fan, this should work without problems, electrically. The problem is that low current in fan mean less temperature dissipation, as a general rule, of course.

Comment: A 12V fan will not work on 1.5V. On 9, 7, maaayybe 5V. But not 1.5V. Since it works with just 2 pins, disconnect the third pin and try it with your psu. Make sure the fan pinout matches the original fan, i.e. use a multimeter to check which one is V+ and which is ground.

Comment: Fans are (usually) not modulated by varying their DC voltage but using PWM, i.e. pulsing a 12V voltage on and off rapidly, with varying pulse widths, to set its speed. You would not expect any 12V fan to start up with just 1.5V. As others have noted, you've probably not connected it correctly.

Comment: I do genuinely appreciate everyone's comments. Using an ohm meter and two other people's confirmation of the wiring, we can safely rule out, "It's just not connected right". The ohm meter makes that pretty obvious since one and only one combination registers anything.

Comment: Do you have a spare 4 pin Molex connector from the power supply? You could just plug it in directly with one of the supplied adaptors.

Comment: @Passerby see update 4 - answer 3-4.5V is enough to turn on a 12V fan it seems.

Comment: @Finbarr so this computer doesn't have any molex connectors but I have a spare power supply! I'm working on getting it out of another computer now

Comment: @Finbarr - Experiment complete - see update #5

Comment: @StarCat it looks like PWM is unique to 4-pin fans whereas 3-pin fans are just DC. Source: https://www.makeuseof.com/dc-vs-pwm-fans-which-is-better/#:~:text=PWM%20fans%20will%20usually%20set,pin%20connectors%20on%20your%20motherboard.

Comment: How are the wire colors assigned to the 3 pins on the original fan? Black should be GND, red = 12 V, yellow = tacho. It may have another pin assignment than the Noctua fan.

Comment: Noctua seems to give 2 pulses / round [(interesting whitepaper)](https://noctua.at/media/wysiwyg/Noctua_PWM_specifications_white_paper.pdf). The original fan may give more or less pulses per round. Also, the pullup on the tacho signal may be a bit different. At last, there could be a current control on the fan supply. If so, a parallel resistor (properly dimensioned) could lift the consumption of the noctua towards that of the original fan. At best you measure the current on the original fan. Maybe yor DMM could also measure the tacho frequency on the original if it has Hz range.

Answer (score 2):

PSUs use cheaper 3-wire fans, and control the fan speed by chopping the +12V supply. The fan has to deal with the chop and still work reliably: its controller needs to have some local filtering for the driver IC to make logic power even when chop is happening.

You said your new Noctua fan runs on 9V DC, but it does not work in the PSU. Why? It could be that it isn't happy with the PSU's PWM chop. It's probably failing when the duty cycle is really low. You measured 1.5V on the +12V line, which would correspond to about a 12% duty cycle. And by 'fail', it could be that the controller doesn't start the motor, or it doesn't make a correct tachometer signal.

Speaking of which, fan tachs make 2 pulses per revolution. That's pretty standard (it's literally an Intel standard for PC fans, be they 3 or 4-wire types.)

Sad to say, you may have to try different brand 3-wire fans that can tolerate the PWM. Try to find the same brand of fan that's in the PSU for example.

Another idea: harvest a fan from a blown up PSU.

Comment: Maybe someone will try this in the future and can confirm if this works for them - I just exchanged the PSU with the manufacturer in the end

Answer (score 1):

The original fan is a DC fan meaning that it has positive negative and a tach/signal cable. This means the PSU detects the tach signal as 0 and then supplies power as needed for that tach signal/thermal needs of the PSU and adjusts voltage to control fan speed.

The fans you have probably have either a incompatible tach signal or are lf PWM fans which work very differently on how they are configured to run in a setup. Which would make sense if they are "nicer more expenive fans". PWM is nice if you have LED's on the fan etc as the fan always gets full power but the fan speed isn't controlled via voltage as such.

If you hook up an LED fan in DC mode on a motherboard you will notice the fan speed and the LED intensity will scale together, in PWM mode the LEDs will maintain correct brightness.

Comment: PWM fans are 4 wire by nature. Mine is 3 wire https://www.makeuseof.com/dc-vs-pwm-fans-which-is-better/#:~:text=PWM%20fans%20will%20usually%20set,pin%20connectors%20on%20your%20motherboard